# gmail api batch request to get multiple messages at once golang

Tags: go, gmail-api

Is there a batch Get messages? from the golang client library?

I dont see it 
https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/gmail/v1

i can get a list of message ids, but have to get the message per Id, one at a time.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direction you want, for example, how about using [Batching Requests](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch)?

Comment: yeah still seems like the only way, which is to be deprecated < a year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer

There is a [Github issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/issues/179) on the Go client's repo regarding this topic, and apparently it is not likely to see support for this feature anytime soon. It may, however, be implemented in the next generation of the client.

#### Possible workaround

You can implement yourself the batching feature, by making HTTP calls to the `www.googleapis.com/batch` or `www.googleapis.com/batch/api/version` endpoints. The former is due to be deprecated in [August 12, 2020](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch) but you can still use the latter past this date for *homogeneous* requests (in your case, doing GET requests based on messageId, you should have no problem doing so). You can read more about this in the following Official Google Developers Blog post: https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/discontinuing-support-for-json-rpc-and.html